# how to set characterEscapeHandler for moxy jaxb

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to set custom `characterEscapeHandler` for moxy jaxb but getting exception:

> javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler value: ..

I do it (and it works for standart jaxb) by adding `com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler` property to `marshallerProperties` of `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller`.

I know about XmlCdata. but i don't want **!Cdata[[**.. will be added, i just want don't escape characters (without adding Cdata).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently in the process of adding support for the JAXB RI's `CharacterEscapeHandler` to [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  You can track our progress using the following bug:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/370589

You will be able to use either the RI property and `CharacterEscapeHandler` class, or the MOXy equivalent.  This support will be checked in this week, and a nightly download of EclipseLink 2.4.0 will be available at:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

I will update my answer once the feature has been checked in.